# не подключается шрифт в CSS

Tags: css

Есть шрифт. Скачан из интернета, открывается на локальном компьютере, все отлично
пытаюсь его примерить к обычной странице на обычном хостинге

```
<!--
тупо HTML страница, файл со шрифтом TTF лежит рядом с HTML файлом, т.е. пути правильные ( index.html и fontawesome-webfont.ttf )
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <style>
    @font-face{
        font-family:FontAwesome,
        src:url(fontawesome-webfont.ttf)
    }
    *,html,body,div{
        font-size:55px;
        font-family:'FontAwesome';
    }
    </style>
    <div>
        en-test<br>
        ru-тест
    </div>
</body>
```

Собственно, подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

p.s. Скобки в src:url уже ставил, font-family указан верно. Даже не понимаю, где не так написал

p.p.s.
[пример страницы с шрифтом](https://my-ola.ru/index_font.html)

Comment: А что значит "открывается на локальном компьютере"? Он на локальном компьютере применяется к веб-странице?

Comment: сори, не ответил. беру html страницу, перетаскиваю в браузер, страница отображается с указанным шрифтом. Кстати удалил шрифт из системы, что бы остался только тот, что подключается к странице - шрифт перестал на странице отображаться. вотЪ

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  src: url("./fontawesome-webfont.ttf") format("truetype");
}
```

А так?

Comment: Точка с запятой после `font-family: "FontAwesome"`

Comment: А что вы конкретно хотите достичь и что именно у вас не работает. Из чего вы сделали вывод, что шрифт не применяется?

Comment: ну, если шрифт будет подключен, что это сразу будет видно, в место стандартного ( с засечками ) . Подключение шрифта на свой, или кастомный - это для изменения стандартного шрифта

Comment: Обновил код. С путями, возможно проблема. В консоли разработчика (F12) ошибки выводились какие-то?

Comment: консоль пуста, т.к. с путями и тегами все норм

Comment: @sergey, я Вам там выше задал вопрос, Вы его почему-то игнорируете. У Вас на локальной машине подключается шрифт? Только на хостинге не работает? Или Вы на локальной даже не проверяли - сразу на хостинг закинули?

Comment: сори, пропустил. на локальной машине - норм

Comment: @sergey, а ссылка есть на страницу на хостинге? чтоб глянуть

Comment: my-ola точка ru/index_font.html

Comment: @sergey, я открыл отладчик в хроме и в разделе Sources не вижу на хостинге шрифта - только страницу index_font.html. Либо Вы не залили шрифт на сервер, либо залили в какое-то другое место, поэтому путь неправильный. Либо хостинг по каким-то причинам блокирует Ваш файл со шрифтом, считая его небезопасным.

Comment: ну, если вбить адрес сайта + дописать шрифт, то сам шрифт присутствует. придеться грешить на хостинг my-ola точка ru/fontawesome-webfont.ttf

Comment: @sergey, в том-то и дело, что там присутствует непонятно что - какой-то битый файл возможно. По ссылке шрифт не должен открываться в браузере  - он должен сразу скачиваться (во всяком случае, в хроме так). Вот как пример: https://expogreen.ru/bitrix/templates/pzn-new/fonts/Pattaya-Regular.ttf